# What is the purpose of LAN IP addresses?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, frame

whats the purpose of local IP addresses if there are mac addresses? ARP maps mac addresses to IP addresses but I don't see why it's needed, because I thought data on LANs are sent as frames which  only care about the mac addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what happens if you want to talk to a macine that *isn't* on your local area network (such as StackOverflow).

IP allows routing of packets anywhere, not just locally in your current network segment and, though it's mostly over Ethernet *now,* IP can equally well work over other underlying layers, giving a consistent view to the upper layers. This is vital given how much stuff is actually built on IP (DNS, FTP, SSH, HTTP and so on).

Machines almost certainly will cache IP-to-ethernet details to speed up subsequent transfers so the impact of translation on the LAN isn't so bad.

Comment: I asked about LAN IP addresses not IP addresses in general.

Comment: @Dan, you'll probably find that there's no real advantage since ARP details will be cached so you may as well use IP for everything rather than trying to figure out what's local and what's not. _Especially_ if your local LAN IP addresses may change (DHCP and so on) - ARP allows for _automated discovery_ whereas if you used hardcoded MAC addresses, you'd have to change them.

Comment: @ paxdiablo so the only purpose of lan IP addresses to is to make it easier for applications to transition from communicating over Lan to WAN or vice versa easier? I don't understand what you mean by using hardcoded mac addresses, these don't change so why would it be more difficult to use them?

Comment: MAC addresses _can_ change though it's rare. I've seen cards that have that capability. But that's beside the point. If you only want to communicate in a LAN, you could use ethernet only, but you'd have to provide your own comms stack. Ethernet is machine level addressing like IP, so you won't get port-level addressing like with TCP.

Comment: In addition, all that other stuff like dns, dhcp, arp, ftp, and so on, is built on top of tcp/ip.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't necessarily mean on top in terms of the protocol stack, rather they're all intertwined.

Comment: @paxdiablo is correct.  The goal of IP addresses is to seamlessly blend local and remote networks.  The reason nobody writes MAC-addressed applications any more is that all the decent programming interfaces are for TCP/IP.

Comment: @paxdiablo 1) he asked about the purpose of LAN IP addresses not IP addresses at all 2) LAN could've possibly worked without IP layer, I believe the main reason for LAN IP creation was to merge together different physical/data link layers such as Token Ring and Ethernet.

Answer (score 1):

Long ago and far away, there was more to the world than Ethernet LANs, and application writers didn't care whether your PC was attached to an Ethernet, a Token Ring, an XNS net, or dial-up.  IP provides a layer of abstraction and coherence across the top of all those and many more, allowing application authors to ignore the differences between them.